# Rails - Decrease Views loading time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, google-cloud-storage

I've added paperclip and Google cloud for image uploading and storage. This caused drastic increase of Views loading time (from 400 ms to 12000 - 14000 ms). Images are resized by paperclip and about 8 kb each.

What can be done to decrease Views loading time? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> I've added paperclip and Google cloud for image uploading and storage.

I assume you're doing the uploading and storage to Google Cloud synchronously "within" a clients request.

```
UserA clicks upload image -> Rails#app -> upload & store in Google Cloud
                                       waiting...upload and store 
                          <-           <-
```

You should instead respond to the users request immediately and do the upload storage and storage with asynchronosly.

```
UserA clicks upload image -> Rails#app -> background process  -> upload & store in Google Cloud
                        respond now
                          <-       

                                          background process <- get answer from Google Cloud
```

There are a few background processing libraries available:

- [Delayed_job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job)
- [Sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq)
- [Resque](https://github.com/resque/resque)

They're all documented pretty well.

Comment: The issue is for already uploaded images on #index or #show pages.

Comment: Oh wow. So the views just contain links to the images on google cloud? How do you measure the page-load time?

Comment: In a view '= image_tag product.image.url(:thumb), class: "img-thumbnail"'; load time was gotten from terminal Completed 200 OK in 5627ms (Views: 5616.2ms | ActiveRecord: 2.2ms). I've recently added dalli gem for memcached cloud on Heroku, its helped.